# Docker Registrator: Connection refused

Tags: docker, consul

```
[root@node1 sysconfig]# docker run -d -v /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock -h node1 progrium/registrator consul://ipaddress:8500
fcb44e6877b12d45c1ddbdf48eaeb210ca632bfbbfd695be96d736330987f10d

[root@node1 sysconfig]# docker logs fcb44e6877b12d45c1ddbdf48eaeb210ca632bfbbfd695be96d736330987f10d
2014/10/07 00:33:51 registrator: Using consul registry backend at consul:ipaddress//:8500
2014/10/07 00:33:51 registrator: dial unix /tmp/docker.sock: connection refused
lxc-start: The container failed to start.
lxc-start: Additional information can be obtained by setting the --logfile and --log-priority options.
```

how do i fix this?
thanks-

Answer (score 0):

Docker requires root privileges, try running `sudo docker run`. Also see https://docs.docker.com/articles/security/.

It is also possible to [give non-root users access](https://docs.docker.com/installation/ubuntulinux/#giving-non-root-access).

Comment: I am already root user. still i did sudo docker run, the error is same. problem could be mount and invoking from /tmp/docker.sock. i have feeling about some setting in docker file, but not sure. need help.

Comment: any help on:registrator: dial unix /tmp/docker.sock: connection refused

Comment: I don't quite know the answer then. I think you are using Consul. Does Consul run under a separate user account?

Comment: Consul is running under same useraccount

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue on CentOS 6.4.

As per [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/installation/binaries/):

> In general, a 3.8 Linux kernel is the minimum requirement for Docker,
>   as some of the prior versions have known issues that are triggered by
>   Docker

I resolved it after I installed the newest stable Linux kernel on the host machine.